# Binary Search number of comparisons

Tags: algorithm

I wrote this recursive piece of code for standard binary search algorithm. I was just wondering when do I add +1 to the comparison counter ? pseud code below

```
Inputs A: Array of Data;
key:Data; L,R:Integer;
Variables m:Integer;
Returns m:Integer;

Begin
If R<L then return -1; fi
m:= (R+L)/2
if key = A[m] then return m; fi
if key > A[m] then
return binSearch(A,key,m+1,R);
Else
return binSearch(A,key,L,m-1);
fi
End
```

Does checking the L and R in the first if statement counts as comparison ? bit confused.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that when you say comparisons you dont mean strictly how many ifs you have, instead you are trying to get to the O(log(n)) complexity for binary search? if that is the case, why not count at the beginning of the function so you count the amount of calls made

Answer (score 0):

In asymtotic analysis, conditional statement considered as O(1).

Because conditional problem is decision problem. 0 or 1.

Comment: sorry i don't understand. I was asking how to count the number of comparisons in this algorithm

Comment: @Tom Do you know recursion tree? It will be helpful to understand I think.